# How to include multiple diretories in the "archive_file" data source?

Tags: python, lambda, terraform, zip, archive-file

```
data "archive_file" "zip_file" {
  type       = "zip"
  source_dir = ["../src", "../../common_lib"]
  output_path = "lambda-code.zip"
}
```

This script doesn't work because the `source_dir` only supports a single directory. Is there any way to include multiple directories?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use [local-exec](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) to provide custom zip operation.